# multidemensional JSON array in URL (POST-request)

Tags: json, url, httprequest

i am trying to build POST-request for one CRM-system, building URL. I have the documentation wich shows methods for this CRM. In my case, i need to add contact, so they have the example of this method, required parameters in JSON.

```
fields:{ 
      "NAME": "Mark", 
      "LAST_NAME": "Jonson", 
      "STATUS_ID": "NEW", 
      "ASSIGNED_BY_ID": 1, 
      "CURRENCY_ID": "USD", 
      "OPPORTUNITY": 12500,
      "PHONE": [ { "VALUE": "555888", "VALUE_TYPE": "WORK" } ] 
  }
```

so i can successfuly add contact in my system, using this `https://myportal.mycrm.com/rest/crm.contact.add?auth=xxxxxxxxxfields[NAME]=A&fields[LAST_NAME]=B`

But i have a huge problem, adding a PHONE, because of its multiple parameters. So i was trying to do it in a lot of ways, for ex. `fields[PHONE[0[VALUE]]]=345678&fields[PHONE[0[VALUE_TYPE]]]=WORK`, but neither was success. Maybe someone can help me with it?

P.S. i need to do it only in URL, so it is not an option for me to use json-parsing, php, http-request-builder etc

Comment: POST request parameters do not go in the url

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are trying to make a POST-request, but what you've really done is GET-request. Please take a [look](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp).

Comment: why is it get-request , if i have already CREATED a contact. So it can not be a GET-request. The problem is only with adding complex parameter PHONE, i can not just add in URL like `fields[PHONE]=55555` as i did with names `fields[NAME]=A`.  I just cant figure this one out `"PHONE": [ { "VALUE": "555888", "VALUE_TYPE": "WORK" } ] ` - what to do with it in  URL

Comment: Johnathan Cause when you are using request string like this www.example.com/test.php?param=a&blah=asd it's a get request. To use post you need to use html forms or js ajax methods.

Comment: ok, but this is not the point. If i can create a NAME , i surely can create a PHONE also in the same request - the point is to write parameters correctly in URL.